# How to write a simple Rust asynchronous proxy using futures "0.3" and hyper "0.13.0-alpha.4"?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, future, hyper

I am trying to rewrite the proxy [example](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/05_http_server_example.html) of [Asynchronous Programming in Rust](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html) book by migrating to :

```
futures-preview = { version = "0.3.0-alpha.19", features = ["async-await"]}`
hyper = "0.13.0-alpha.4"`
```

from:

```
futures-preview = { version = "=0.3.0-alpha.17", features = ["compat"] }`
hyper = "0.12.9"
```

The current example converts the returned `Future` from a `futures 0.3` into a `futures 0.1`, because `hyper = "0.12.9"` is not compatible with `futures 0.3`'s async/await.

My code:

```rust
use {
    futures::future::{FutureExt, TryFutureExt},
    hyper::{
        rt::run,
        service::{make_service_fn, service_fn},
        Body, Client, Error, Request, Response, Server, Uri,
    },
    std::net::SocketAddr,
    std::str::FromStr,
};

fn forward_uri<B>(forward_url: &'static str, req: &Request<B>) -> Uri {
    let forward_uri = match req.uri().query() {
        Some(query) => format!("{}{}?{}", forward_url, req.uri().path(), query),
        None => format!("{}{}", forward_url, req.uri().path()),
    };

    Uri::from_str(forward_uri.as_str()).unwrap()
}

async fn call(
    forward_url: &'static str,
    mut _req: Request<Body>,
) -> Result<Response<Body>, hyper::Error> {
    *_req.uri_mut() = forward_uri(forward_url, &_req);
    let url_str = forward_uri(forward_url, &_req);
    let res = Client::new().get(url_str).await;
    res
}

async fn run_server(forward_url: &'static str, addr: SocketAddr) {
    let forwarded_url = forward_url;
    let serve_future = service_fn(move |req| call(forwarded_url, req).boxed());

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(serve_future);
    if let Err(err) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", err);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Set the address to run our socket on.
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:9061";
    let futures_03_future = run_server(url, addr);
    run(futures_03_future);
}
```

First, I receive this error for `server` in `run_server` function:

> the trait `tower_service::Service<&'a
>   hyper::server::tcp::addr_stream::AddrStream>` is not implemented for
>   `hyper::service::service::ServiceFn<[closure@src/main.rs:35:35: 35:78
>   forwarded_url:_], hyper::body::body::Body>`

Also, I cannot use `hyper::rt::run` because it might have been implemented differently in `hyper = 0.13.0-alpha.4`.

I will be grateful if you tell me your ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this [issue](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/1650#issuecomment-433526852), to create a new service for each connection  you need to create  [MakeService](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.18/hyper/service/trait.MakeService.html) in `hyper = "0.13.0-alpha.4"`. You can create `MakeService` with a closure by using `make_service_fn`.

> Also, I cannot use `hyper::rt::run` because it might have been implemented differently in `hyper = 0.13.0-alpha.4`.

Correct, under the hood `hyper::rt::run` was calling `tokio::run`, it has been removed from the api but currently  i don't know the reason. You can run your future with calling `tokio::run` by yourself or use `#[tokio::main]` annotation. To do this you need to add `tokio` to your cargo:

```
#this is the version of tokio inside hyper "0.13.0-alpha.4"
tokio = "=0.2.0-alpha.6"
```

then change your `run_server` like this:

```rust
async fn run_server(forward_url: &'static str, addr: SocketAddr) {
    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_service_fn(move |_| {
        async move { Ok::<_, Error>(service_fn(move |req| call(forward_url, req))) }
    }));
    if let Err(err) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", err);
    }
}
```

and `main` :

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> () {
    // Set the address to run our socket on.
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    let url = "http://www.google.com:80"; // i have tested with google 

    run_server(url, addr).await
}
```